# How do I use Zigbee to communicate to smartphone

Tags: wireless, smartphone, zigbee

I need to monitor how many smart phones are connected to a wireless network in a certain area. I found out that Zigbee can be used to accomplish this task. I need to at least differentiate each phone connected. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing anything in regards to Zigbee, you could use the BSSID of the device as your unique identifier. Every WiFi radio has a unique BSSID. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

ZigBee (802.15.4) and Wi-Fi (802.11) are different networking standards.  They both use 2.4GHz, but a ZigBee radio won't be able to identify nodes on a Wi-Fi network.

Answer (score 3):

Zigbee (IEEE 802.15.4) and WiFi (IEEE 802.11) are two different PHY/MAC specifications. The first thing you have to do is:

1. Build a gateway between the Zigbee and WiFi networks.
2. Each smartphone should be capable of connecting to the Zigbee network.
3. Each smartphone should act as end device and Zigbee controller
   should track the position of each smartphone. This controller should
   be connected to Wifi via gateway [1]. Then you can easily track
   number of smartphones connected to a network.